# Metro layout for views

Tags: 7, views, theming

Any way to achieve metro style layout for Views items?

E.g.:
[image]

I was thinking maybe there are modules or something. Was searching for something like Masonry, but didn't find any.

Comment: I'm not sure if there was any modules available that is readily integrated with Views. I would use drupal's render API and isotope.js. That way you have more control over the output/layout.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I checked isotope.js, but it only sorts and filters. Also it is not even free.

Comment: There other similar JS plugins that will give you the functionality you are looking for. I mentioned isotope.js, because that's what I have used and liked. It does actually have several different display options, masonry is one of them. If you are looking for free plugins, I'm sure simple google search will show you what you are looking for: salvattore.js, mason.js, freetile.js are a few I came across. The nice thing with using render API is that you can experiment with these different plugins and find one that fits. Good luck